# All custom moderator flags declined with same reason

Tags: support, declined-flags, moderation

All of my recent custom moderator flags were just declined with the same reason:

> declined - Please use the "Not an answer" flag if the post is not in English

What happened?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This afternoon, at approximately 2020-05-19 13:22:00Z, I made a mistake which resulted in a number of declined flags with two possible incorrect reasons:

- Please use the "Needs details or clarity" flag/close reason if the post is not in English
- Please use the "Not an answer" flag if the post is not in English

If any of you were affected by this, and the content still requires attention, please re-flag the post. Any inconvenience caused is regretted. Please accept my sincerest apologies.

---

**Update:** the flag declines were reverted, so they can be reviewed and handled again. All associated flag bans should be fixed up as well. --Adam

Comment: I am banned due to this now ...

Comment: @TemaniAfif that is totally legit ... ;)

Comment: @TemaniAfif sorry, I'll personally look into your flags and follow-up if necessary

Comment: Is there no method to correct these incorrectly rejected flags without users going into meta and seeing this post?

Comment: Unfortunately not, there is a very limited recent history but that's it. I have already handled whatever I could from there. Also only spam flags can be changed to disputed.

Comment: I kindly suggest you make this thread `featured`, at least for a while; I was ready to post here re 5 flags for cross-postings and potential plagiarism that were declined like that.

Comment: @desertnaut it's still the top question in meta and will remain for a while. No need to feature it and attract user not intrested with. Anyone who got banned will for sure come here to figure out the issue.

Comment: Have you thought about taking a break from the moderator queue? Perhaps a 7-day one?

Comment: @RobertColumbia that presumably has some unrelated consequences that are arguably worse than one mistake that can be corrected: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/49375303#49375303 . You have a choice here: accept that a mistake was made and move on, or risk no custom flag handling for a week.

Comment: @Zoe I raise the same argument used by moderators when banning users from the review queues - no review is better than bad review.

Comment: @RobertColumbia For other queues, I'd agree. The thing about mod reviews is that these cover mod flags and comment flags. Every single time the community can't control a heated argument, only a mod can stop it. The consequences of letting a heated conflict (or one of the other matters only mods can efficiently handle) escalate is a hell of a lot worse than a close-worthy question wrongly being left open.

Comment: I think this is just one good reason why the system should allow for changing of flag-status. @RobertColumbia If you feel strongly about this, there's nothing to stop you from asking a new Question. But given that bans on reviewers have been lifted once the reviewer has realized their mistake, I can't see a self-imposed moderator-queue ban lasting longer than a second in this case.

Comment: Secondly, there's a massive difference between a mistake and consistently making mistakes. Most of the "requires editing" users don't understand what the option means. Mistakes happen, and they're a different category from misunderstanding and/or intentionally handling reviews incorrectly

Comment: @RobertColumbia I don't see any declined flags in your flag history caused by this? Anyway the issue that caused this has already been fixed.

Comment: @SamuelLiew I know, but the issue is *why* the mistake was made and what steps need to be taken to prevent its recurrence. It's not you specifically, it's just that I've picked up on a bit of a double-standard attitude among moderators here - they say "sorry" and try to move on if they make a mistake (often even admitting that they weren't paying attention or didn't research the issue enough), but come down hard on ordinary users who don't pay 100% attention.

Comment: @RobertColumbia If more mods were active I'd be more tempted to agree, but if Sam is the *only* mod currently working on queues, he'd just come back in a week with twice the workload, that's totally unreasonable to expect

Comment: @RobertColumbia users who get review suspended can appeal. That especially applies to those who make mistakes or misclick. Several have also been manually lifted. The review bans are to get the attention of the reviewers, because there's no better systems in place for it.

Comment: @RobertColumbia I'm not sure I would compare an automation error when handling the mod queue with reviewers that click a button one at a time. There might be double-standards but you need to find a way better case to make your point. This one is not it.

Comment: Ah i understand why the custom flags went from 380 to 0 today...

Comment: @SamuelLiew I was hit by this, flagging promotional and plagiarized content. Unfortunately, attempting to re-flag some of these gives me "you have already flagged this post for moderator attention"

Comment: ^ not a problem in *my* case, as the posters in question have plenty of other examples to flag instead. But might make things difficult for others.

Comment: Sam if too many things get broken, please keep in mind that you can escalate to CMs for help in cleaning incorrectly declined flags. This is rare thing but technically possible - see [this old example from SU meta](https://meta.superuser.com/a/3356/97481)

Comment: I'm sorry for going into such details here, but I hope the special circumstances created by this could save us all from the burden of a new Meta post: I'm puzzled as to how my 2nd flag for cross-posting [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61698079/machine-learning-on-classifying-speech) was found helpful, but the (closed) post is still there, despite having already an accepted answer in [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/73861/machine-learning-on-classifying-speech). Am I missing something?

Comment: @desertnaut Maybe y'all have rules I'm not aware of but on most other sites I've worked with, cross-posting is a reason to close, not delete.

Comment: What to do about the flags we re-submitted? I've now got a few posts with duplicate pending flags. Just leave 'em as is?

Comment: @MikeM. I think that's easiest. I think mods can see all flags against a post at the same time, so handling the same flag shouldn't cause too much extra work? /shrug

Comment: @Zoe Yeah, that's what I'm assuming, since we can't retract individual flags of the same type, I believe. Just wanted to get some official word, if possible.

Comment: @MikeM. Just leave them. Apologies for y'all needing to do double work but thanks so much for going to the effort.

Comment: @Catija I delete cross-posted questions when there is nothing of value to be salvaged in the copy (e.g., a new question with no answers, or a question with no useful answers). I think that is the standard course of action.

Comment: @SamuelLiew I think I may have been hit by this too. Please check my only declined flag. This is important to me because I am new to this aspect of the site and want to make sure I understand what flags should be raised

Comment: @medic17 Your flag was *correctly* declined for this reason. Stack Overflow moderators do not migrate questions that are not in English, so you should not flag them with a custom flag requesting migration. Instead, simply flag non-English questions as "unsuitable for this site -> unclear".

Comment: Whoa, what @Adam did there is pretty cool.

Comment: Anyway, perhaps I could help with the custom flags while Samuel takes his 7-day sabbatical, @Robert?