# Flag for possible plagiarism of own answer declined due to conflict of interest

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, plagiarism

A while ago I posted an answer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61796171/how-to-reduce-mse-and-improve-r2-in-linear-regression-model), which the OP shortly after accepted. In the meanwhile, a third user had already commented independently corroborating my suggested corrective action.

One day later, and with my answer already accepted, a new SO user flies by, and decides to post another answer; the suggested corrective action was identical, with a different wording, plus a link to and a quote from the documentation, not present in my own one. OP proceeds to change their accepted answer to the new one.

I left some comments under the new answer explaining why this is not a good SO practice (will not repeat them here, as they are irrelevant to this post, and they can still be seen in the link above - EDIT: they have now been removed)). At the same time, I raised a custom flag as:

> Borderline plagiarism of own existing (and at the time of posting accepted) answer.

I have just discovered that the flag was

> declined - you are the author of the other answer. conflict of interest

To make things somewhat more complicated, this was actually the *second* time the subject flag was processed. It was initially one of a whole bunch of custom flags that were [accidentally declined due to an error](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397579/all-custom-moderator-flags-declined-with-same-reason) on May 19. As instructed back then, I immediately re-flagged (same wording), and the flag was processed the same day as

> helpful - the answer looks okay, and quotes from the documentation. perhaps the op is new and the newer answer was easier to understand

In all truth, and despite that the flagged post was not deleted, I personally found this resolution very fair (I would say *masterful*): I chose to read it as "*OK, I can see your point, but it looks borderline indeed; so, let's just leave it there and move on*". Which I happily did.

But, as it turned out, all those flags that were accidentally declined back then were shortly after reverted; and as a result, the subject flag was to be again pending (I admittedly didn't care to go back and manually retract it).

I only found out about the decline last night accidentally, while just inspecting my declined flags.

---

To be clear and precise:

- This is **not** a question about the essence of the flagged post - if it indeed constituted plagiarism or not, and if I was right or wrong in believing so and flagging it as such. I repeat that I was perfectly happy with the way the flag was resolved the first time.
- This is **not** a question about if I was wrong to not retract the already processed flag - I was certainly wrong and should have manually retracted it.
- This is **not** a question about how the very same flag can be both helpful and declined under the same circumstances. Moderators are humans, and [some degree of subjectivity is certainly to be expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397912/very-low-quality-vs-not-an-answer/397913#397913), even more so in a case that I was the very first to admit it was indeed borderline.
- This is **not** a question regarding the flag rejection itself. I would expect it to be declined since already processed (hence a "duplicate"); but I could also perfectly understand a decline with the standard reason, *a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it*.

But choosing to decline such a flag due to a *conflict of interest* with such a general wording is arguably a very different story; it certainly seems to imply some sort of directive/guideline:

> Whenever we happen upon content that we may consider as plagiarism of our own contributions, we are **not** supposed to flag it as such ourselves, since we have by definition a conflict of interest. Only third users, which are expected to be impartial, are supposed to raise such custom flags for alleged plagiarism.

which IMO sounds absurd, to say the least.

Is that so?

Comment: I wasn't aware that it was possible to *revert* moderator flags.

Comment: " Moderators are **just** human beings..." 'Just' in the sense of 'merely', or in the sense of 'fair and upright'?

Comment: @AdrianMole option A holds here.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Not normally, although as OP says there was one high profile example recently where several mod flags were reverted: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397579/all-custom-moderator-flags-declined-with-same-reason

Comment: I wouldn't say that answer was even close to plagiarism. It has the same final response (remove `fit_intercept=False`). Both are very differently written, one (notably not yours), provides a citation. IMO rejecting it as a *"conflict of interest"* is absolutely wrong, but I would agree with it's rejection. (Yes I know this isn't your question. That's why this isn't an answer.)

Comment: Agree that "conflict of interest" is a bad reason.  If i am the owner of any kind of content and someone plagiarizes that content, it should be my right to raise my objection to the plagiarism.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't see two linked answer to be anywhere close to each other - to me (granted I know nothing about the topic, but that is the same for diamond mods) two answers look at the same solution from two very different angles using very different wording and explanations. Claiming that one line of code (presumably the only possible answer) is plagiarism is at least not obvious. And SO actually encourages alternative explanations as different people may be need different explanations and hence such answers are welcome - acceptance by OP may indicate that alternative answer actually was more useful to them personally.

So the flag is basically asking a moderator to investigate if one of those two quite different answers is indeed plagiarizing the other. That is quite a non-trivial amount of work - I expect it to be declined on its own. Being author of the other answer just adds to it - indeed as author of the competing answer you have (as a user of SO *on average*) initiative to remove competition (see [tactical-downvoting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tactical-downvoting) for another manifestation of such initiative). I believe highlighting that initiative was the reason of the "conflict of interests" part of the custom moderator message.

The way I suggest to look at the decline message is - "we can't investigate unclear plagiarism claims. Additionally if you, as it looks like, may have *other* reasons to dislike flagged post, your explanation should be crystal  clear to avoid potential concerns on any revenge/retaliation".

Comment: Makes sense. I'll take it. As said, decline in itself is neither surprising nor the question here. Your reasonable last argument cuts both ways: if you are to use a custom decline message, better be clear and specific, otherwise you run the risk of raising more questions.

Comment: And despite what the question was not about, your arguments regarding the other answer are convincing, too; FWIW, I have just gone back and retracted my own downvote to it (community talks, we listen).