# Very low quality vs not an answer

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, low-quality-posts, not-an-answer, specific-answer

I flagged an answer as very low quality because I think the answer is very low quality and just like a comment,  but it was declined with this reason:

> flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an
>   altogether wrong answer

I raised a flag again as not answer and accepted. So what is different of `very low quality` and `not an answer` flag? I have also reported as not an answer but was rejected for the same reason as very low quality.

[image: Flagging history, showing one declined "very low quality" flag and one helpful "not an answer" flag]

Here is a link to the flagged answer: [Android: No version of NDK matched the requested version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60404457/android-no-version-of-ndk-matched-the-requested-version/62094285#62094285).

Here is the text of the answer at the time it was flagged:

> hay to solve this problem you must indicate to your IDE the version of your NDK in bluil.gradel .

Comment: Related: [Merge the “Not An Answer” and “Very Low Quality” flags into one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318952/merge-the-not-an-answer-and-very-low-quality-flags-into-one). These flag options seem like an exercise in linguistic fussiness.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The difference was two different moderators. :-)

Your first "very low quality" flag was declined by moderator A, who simultaneously declined someone else's "not an answer" flag on that same answer.

Your second "not an answer" flag was accepted by moderator B, who simultaneously accepted someone else's "not an answer" flag on that same answer.

The reason I bring this up is to say two things:

1. Practically speaking, there is no difference in how moderators handle "very low quality" and "not an answer" flags.

   Both types of flags mean, "this does not answer the question and/or has serious quality problems, making it in need of immediate deletion". That's how they're interpreted by moderators, and they're processed virtually identically. The fact that the moderator who declined your "very low quality" flag also declined a "not an answer" flag for exactly the same reason is compelling evidence of this.
2. Since moderators are humans, and flags are subjective, there is going to be some natural variation in how flags are interpreted/handled.

   This scenario proves it, where you basically raised the same flag twice, back to back, on the same answer, with no intervening edits, and yet the flags were handled in two different ways by two different moderators each using their own judgment.

I was neither moderator A nor moderator B in this scenario, but I can totally understand why moderator A declined the flag for the reason given. It *looks* like the answer is proposing a solution to the problem: "indicate to your IDE the version of your NDK in bluil.gradel". I have no idea whether that is the correct answer or not, but it is not the job of moderators to judge the technical accuracy of answers. The person even says, in comments underneath his own answer:

> No it's a answer for the question, to solve this problem you must indicate to your application the version of your NDK in bluid.gradel in this case 21.0.6113669. the IDE take a default version the last one worked all this is caused by the upgrade of gradel.

So it makes sense that the "not an answer" flag would be declined. You say that the answer is "just like a comment", but I don't see anything in there that would be appropriate in a comment. If it's an attempt to answer the question, then it should be posted as an answer.

Related reading: [When to flag an answer as "not an answer"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer)

Frankly, looking at this more carefully, I don't really understand the decision of moderator B to delete this answer. It doesn't look like something that moderators would generally delete in response to *any* kind of flag.

Especially since the answer has now been edited by its original author to add a code snippet, I think this definitely qualifies as an answer by our standards, so I've undeleted it. (I've also deleted the comment that I quoted above, and others, since the undeletion of the answer made them obsolete.)