# "Very Low Quality" answer flags all declined around the same time

Tags: support, declined-flags, flag-ban

Just now I had 3 "Very Low Quality" answer flags that all received **"declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it"**, resulting in me getting flag banned.

1. [Flag 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63534315/my-raycast-is-not-activating-my-enemies-death-in-unity-3d/63534422#63534422) (this one has been deleted, so if you don't have enough rep to see deleted answers you will not be able to see it)
2. [Flag 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63533818/unity-ads-stuck-in-loop/63534339#63534339)
3. [Flag 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63534553/how-to-import-xr-legacy-input-helpers-and-multiplayer-hlapi-into-unity-2020-1-2f/63534616#63534616) (also deleted)

Now, I've researched this a bit already, but I still don't think I'm using the flag incorrectly or anything. If these truly were declined for the correct reasons, please explain to me why these flags were wrong so I can correct how I'm using flags.

Comment: Same thing is happening for me. The questions I have flagged are either closed or unanswered but I received this .. declined your...

Comment: They all either answer or attempt to answer the Question. "very low quality" flags are the same as "not an answer" flags. They are meant to convey: This should be deleted ASAP. This may help you to understand why your flags are being declined: [When to flag an answer as “not an answer”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer) and [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

Comment: This may help you too. It describes how to handle the posts in the queue, you send the Answer to: [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue). Moderators will handle them the same way. I noticed that two of the posts you linked to was getting deleted in the Low Quality Posts queue. I assume a moderator intervened.

Comment: @null_override Your problem is slightly different. You are raising "very low quality" flags on *questions*. You are correct to be flagging those questions, but you are using the wrong type of flag. "Very low quality" means "this question needs to be deleted by a moderator". Those questions didn't; they just needed to be closed by the community. So, what you should be raising instead are flags to recommend that the question be closed because it is unsuitable for this site as currently written (**flag → needs improvement → <pick a reason>**).

Comment: @Scratte Thx for the feedback.I agree and understand that the "Not an Answer" flag is only for answers that literally are not attempts at being an answer, as stated in the sources that you've provided. But where does it say that "Very Low Quality" flags are the same as "Not an Answer" flags? And if that is the case, why do we even have the option for "Very Low Quality"? I ask because Flag 3 is literally telling the OP of the question to search for his answer on Google, Youtube, and GitHub, so one would think that that would be considered a "Very Low Quality" answer, but even this got declined.

Comment: You may find [What is it I don't understand about the “very low quality” flag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/314661) a good read. But your other source is: *me* :) Both flags puts the Answer into the Low Quality Posts review queue, where the Answer is handled independently of what flag was raised to put it there. There's only one difference between the two flags which is that the "not an answer" flag is persistent, while the "very low quality" flag unfortunately(?) will be dismissed as helpful if there's an edit on the post.

Comment: @CodyGray thanks for your informative reply.I am currently banned from flagging for a week and I was also a bit confused about these tags.I thought to write about my problem in here, but I think I should research a bit more.May be the flags should explain things more clearly.

Comment: Since the other linked post was about Questions, I'll add [Very low quality vs not an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397912/very-low-quality-vs-not-an-answer) and [Merge the “Not An Answer” and “Very Low Quality” flags into one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318952/merge-the-not-an-answer-and-very-low-quality-flags-into-one)

Comment: I'm fairly confident that "Whenever the post is edited, whether it is in the queue or not, whether the editor is the flagger themselves or not, the flag is marked helpful and the post gets an automatic downvote" of the last linked post isn't accurate. I believe this has been changed and an automatic downvote is no longer applied.

Comment: Flag 3 has also been deleted. If 2 out of the three flags resulted into the desired action being done (deletion of the flagged post), I wonder what happened that the moderator didn't see it that way?

Comment: Note that users with [20K privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) can vote to delete Answers. This is unrelated to the expected actions of a moderator and also unrelated to the actions that is suppose to happen in the Low Quality Posts review queue.

Answer (score 3):

Let's consider one of the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63533818/unity-ads-stuck-in-loop/63534339#63534339):

> I cant do much if I can't see the GameManager Script but you should be able to create a bool and set it to true first. Set a if statement and ask weather that bool is true or false. If true it will run the code then at the end set the bool to false. If false (return;)

This is a terrible answer, but it does in fact make an *attempt* to answer the question. It is also neither spam, rude (trolling, hate speech, or unintelligible gibberish), or a non-English answer. This means that it is *not flaggable*. See [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) for an in-depth discussion on what constitutes a flaggable non-answer.

If you think this is a terrible answer, you can downvote it. That's what downvotes are *for*.

Any of the following would be flaggable:

- Hi, I like turtles. (NAA)
- The one over here, because clear, vegetables, align Cambodia C code script for the scarf no shoes (classic VLQ, NAA also acceptable)
- Your answer doesn't work, what if I'm running on a Mac with less than 8GB RAM? (NAA)
- How can I upgrade to Windows 10? (NAA)
- High quality dietary supplements, click here quality foreign pharmacy and products canada free shipment (Spam)
- אתה לא יכול לעשות את זה. (NAA - Not English)
- adeopampauitphaeruhafgsdttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttggththdttddtjytjytjom (Rude or NAA)
- You stink. Go eat your own vomit. (Rude)

Comment: Considering that 2 out 3 answers have been deleted, taking that one as example implies that the other ones that were actually deleted were the same or similar, in which case that points to an inconsistency. What the other two answers did that this answer did not which got them deleted?

Comment: @Braiam How is that? Are you sure they were not deleted by votes from regular users with [20K delete privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) as this privilege is suppose to be used? The fact that the Answers are deleted now doesn't imply that a moderator nor that the Low Quality Posts review queue is suppose to delete those posts.

Comment: If "Very Low Quality" is literally exactly the same as "Not an Answer" then I wholeheartedly agree and understand that my flag would have gotten declined. Logically I would think that their answer is technically an answer, but a VLQ answer. This is also the best answer provided of the 3. If my definition of "Very Low Quality" is just different than what was the flag was intending, then I would understand. But so far 90% of the responses have brought up how the answers were technically answers, but I wasn't using the NAA flag.

Comment: @GarrisonBecker sadly, that's not true. There has been feature requests to make the flag one, since the functionality is the same (delete this), but that's another issue. Moderators may apply different criteria for each flag (some of them differ by moderator). If it becomes a "delete this" flag, then you would need to actually clarify that low quality content should also be deleted. BTW, the guidance for deletion is the same no matter who does it: 20kers or moderators. The page of why answers are deleted, includes a non-exhaustive list of reasons.

Comment: @Braiam The 20K delete Answer action is assumed to be made by a subject matter expert that can determine if the Answer is wrong. No such reasoning is applied in the Low Quality Posts review queue or by moderators. So the logic applied is not the same.