# Answer that admits it's answering a different question declined for NAA flag

Tags: discussion, answers, declined-flags, not-an-answer

I recently flagged [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63509039/11047824) as NAA, one that I ran across in the Late Answers review queue. I read through the answer, and came to this line:

> This is the first stackoverflow topic that appears if you Google for this error, so I'm writing my solution to that problem here even if maybe it's not the solution for the OP.

I'm not a subject matter expert in the topic at hand (php), but after reading that line, I decided to flag it NAA because the OP appeared to admit, directly, that this post doesn't attempt to answer the asker's question.

My flag was declined.

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

I've read many posts regaling the nuance of the NAA flag ([wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/11047824)), so I'm familiar with the fact that a post must only *attempt* to answer a question to not qualify, and that answer quality is irrelevant to this distinction.

Did I make a bad judgement call here? Does a solution to a different problem really qualify as an attempt to answer the asker's question? Or are there further details in the answer that I should've taken note of?

Comment: Dunno.  It's an answer to "something" I guess.  I would expect though that it get DVed from orbit though, if it is not related to the OP.

Comment: There's a rumour that an Answer that attempts to answer **any** Question is not "not an answer". It doesn't have to attempt answering the Question it's on.

Comment: The answer you link to says it all: "Do not use the "not an answer" flag for wrong answers."

Comment: Curious why you would flag it at all if you aren't familiar with the subject?

Comment: My post at its core revolved around the question of whether "useful answer to related but different question" qualifies as NAA. The consensus is evidently *no*! I would raise that I didn't think of this as a "wrong" answer; I thought NAA could be understood as "Not An Answer *to this question*", which is evidently an incorrect interpretation.

Comment: I think maybe you should also read [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue)

Comment: I have one answer that explicitly contains two answers, because I got tired of people landing on the question through Google and downvoting me because I didn't answer the question that *they* had.

Comment: I think what the answerer was saying in that case was that the answer they were providing was an answer to the question even if it might not work in OP's specific case, which often happens for highly-technical questions like this. They work for one person and not for another, and so you can have multiple valid answers. That's how I read the answer in question.

Comment: For what it's worth, there is an upvoted proposal to add 'Off Topic' to the list of answer flags. The [top answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/377551/7795130) demonstrates very effectively why it's foolish to restrict off-topic answers from being flagged just because they are still technically answers.

Comment: Please consider all use cases for Stack Exchange. I need to find out how to do something, a very high percentage of Google hits are (in my case) StackOverflow posts. I really hate narrow answers that go sometimes to great lengths to only address the OP exact question rather than taking a little more effort (sometimes a little less effort) to provide a general solution that also addresses the OPs question and is useful for everyone else reading the post. The focus should be on helping the community rather than (just) a single user; answers that do so should be upvoted, not be flagged & deleted.

Comment: Flagging answers that aren't even in the same zip code as the question unfortunately isn't a good use of your time. I've flagged (completely unrelated and useless) Java answers to C++ questions and even that got declined. I think anything that sounds even slightly like a "code thing" will be declined, even if it's the wrong language, wrong tech, or if the answerer didn't even read the question at all. Even something like "Dereference a pointer and make a UI in Visual Basic to reformat the vector and sort your dependency injections."

Comment: @Scratte _"It doesn't have to attempt answering the Question it's on."_ Henceforth, all my answers shall be `42`. (jk jk)

Comment: @Michael That's the obvious loophole, that Davy M kindly points out above in [his link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/377551/11047824) lol

Comment: It is a NAA2UQ.

Comment: How would removing an answer that is useful to people finding this question through Google be useful to anyone? I'd suggest spending your effort elsewhere.

Comment: I guess it would have been better for the person writing that answer, to first create a matching question, instead of his prologue. If his question also contains that error message, and maybe more words from his scope, it should easily appear first in google. It is not wrong to answer ones own  questions. Maybe there is an even more efficient solution to the problem he had and solved, that someone else might chip in? It would be madness if everyone starts to answer the answerers question, rather than the ops.

Comment: @derM True, although it'd be even better to find an existing question which matches the answer, because very likely there actually is one.

Comment: @derM I don't see enough difference there to make a new question that isn't just a duplicate of the first. Honestly, even the answer looks the same, since both answers are "fix autoloader"--just two different ways to do it, depending on the tools being used.

Comment: @charlietfl You don't have to be familiar with the technology to flag it.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If a single sentence of an answer makes you reach for the flag dialog then you and I won't have enough flags, ever ;)

I present you this sentence found in that same answer.

> The solution to my problem was to simply run the command composer dump-autoload and then try again to run my test suite.

I'm not a subject matter expert either but I can totally imagine that to be a useful answer. If not to the question asked then at least to another question.

That means deleting that answer is removing value and as such an NAA flag is the wrong option. Declining that flag is correct.

I give you that the answer has a lot of fluff and it might need an edit to  bring it down to the essentials.

If the answer is any good will be known in 6 to 8 weeks, when the votes are in.

See also: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

Comment: All solid points. If a post's being *useful* trumps the fact that the post doesn't answer OP, then NAA is absolutely an incorrect call. Thanks for the input!

Comment: @zcoop98 the point here is that the answerer isn't saying "I'm going to answer an entirely different question", what they're saying is essentially "I had this same error message and google led me here, and although I can't guarantee that this will solve it in the OP's case, here's what solved it in mine". They're making an attempt to answer the question, just not guaranteeing that it'll solve it in the global case. Does that make sense?

Comment: @zcoop98 and to add this - answers on SO don't serve to solve the OP's problem.  They serve to solve everyone who has the same "issue" (including the OP).  So multiple answers with different approaches are excellent

Answer (score 21):

If the answer is for a different question, at most it may be a wrong answer for the current question. Wrong answers are not *Not An Answer*. Wrong answers need to be downvoted and delete-voted by the community.

The NAA flag should be used for answers which are absolutely not answers such as "asking a question" for example.

Comment: This makes me think "Not an answer" should be renamed into something much more clear, something like like "Not answering", because I always read "Not an answer" as "Not an answer to this question" (in which case "I ate a banana" wouldn't count as an answer, when in fact it does right now, albeit a completely off topic one).

Comment: @Clockwork How could "I ate a banana" or a recipe for cooking crepes be a valid Answer to any Question on Stack Overflow?

Comment: @Scratte I don't think it is, but lately I am completely confused about how flags work that I stopped using them altogether. My NAA flags were declined because answers that had nothing to do with the question (or bad ones) still counted as being useful.

Comment: @Clockwork Check out the comments to [“Very Low Quality” answer flags all declined around the same time](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400566/very-low-quality-answer-flags-all-declined-around-the-same-time). Links to posts there should give you some clarity. I believe the same posts are also linked here, but a little more scattered.

Comment: Re *"If the answer is for a different question, at most it may be a wrong answer for the current question."* - Highly upvoted meta posts disagree. See "orange" when the question is about "apples": [Undo's post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue) which refers to [Skog9's post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/227874).

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve [On that note](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377539/can-we-add-off-topic-to-the-list-of-answer-flags/377551#377551)

Answer (score 14):

I think what the answerer was saying in this case is that the answer they were providing was an answer to the question, even if it might not work in OP's specific case, which often happens for highly-technical questions like this. A solution works for one person and not for another, and so you can have multiple valid answers. That's how I read the answer in question.

Comment: Exactly, that's how I read it too. It's definitely answering (substantially) the same question, just in a scenario that was slightly different from the accepted answer - it looks like the poster already had the solution found in the accepted answer in place, but it still did not work without a slight additional tweak.

Answer (score 9):

To be brutally honest: If a topic is old enough to reach the #1 spot on Google for a vaguely similar topic, it is probably old enough that the OP's problem has either been solved or become irrelevant to them.

At that point, allowing an answer that is not strictly replying to OP's problem is likely to be useful to somebody, whereas insisting on strict adherence to the issue at hand is not really useful to anybody. So I'd say it's reasonable to leave the answer up.

(I also think that SO has a bit of a problem: Currently, when dealing with reports, there are seemingly two options: "I agree with this report" and "This report is wrong and the person who filed it needs to be punished". There is no middle ground of "I think the reported question/answer/comment does not violate this rule but I can see why somebody would think otherwise and file a report".)

Answer (score 7):

> "*...I decided to flag it NAA because the OP appeared to admit, directly, that this post doesn't attempt to answer the asker's question.*"

What about if the asker or anyone else who searches for an answer to the same question, find this answer post relevant and helpful regardless of what the poster itself or you think?

Just because one think *it would not* be appropriate doesn't automatically mean *it is*.

Maybe the answer gives part wise an answer and helpful information but the poster (and you) isn't/aren't sure about that.

Also many times questions on Stack Overflow are implementation related. Sometimes even a questioner later adds information that s/he is bond to a specific one, but answers for other implementation are already provided.

Other questions are very broad and no one really exactly know where the solution of the problem lies. Giving an answer which might contain helpful information to solve the problem is good even if it does not 100% answer the question.

Such an answer is then not not-informative. There might be information in that post which helps the questioner itself or others by solving their specific problem although it not *exactly* focus the question.

And that's the point why the quality of an answer and estimating the quality of an answer isn't relevant for flagging an answer as NAA if the post still attempts to answer the question, however badly, *or* is relevant for answering the question.

So, the decline of the flag was IMHO correct.

Comment: "What about if the asker or anyone else who searches for an answer to the same question, find this answer post relevant and helpful regardless of what the poster itself or you think?" - (This is a real question and not sarcastic at all, I'm completely confused lately) You mean, if I find an extremely helpful recipe for cooking crepes on a question about Angular, it would stlll fit as a good answer?

Comment: @Clockwork No. What I mean is just because someone feel it wouldn't fit *at all* doesn't mean it really doesn't fit *at all*. I added an example to my answer as well but let's face it: For example, one ask about how to make cookies with an oven. This person has trouble with the handling of the temperature and duration, that the cookies get fine crunchy. S/he ask about it and someone give an answer how s/he made the perfect cake on which cookies were applied on the surface. Although the answer does not exactly answer the question, it gives useful information...

Comment: ... under which circumstances a similar task with equal elements went well. Just because one think this information isn't useful, doesn't mean it is. That's what I meant. I added something to my answer as well.

Answer (score 4):

Think about the alternative. If you posted a similar question just to answer that the solution was different in your particular case, your new question would most likely be flagged as a duplicate.

IMO, solutions to issues with multiple causes, and especially identical error messages with multiple causes, should be collected in the same Q&A. Not only is this more useful to future visitors, but probably makes things easier on flaggers and reviewers.

Comment: In particular, if you put your hand over the other accepted answer and ignore that one sentence, it reads as a valid answer to the question that was asked.

Comment: *" If you posted a similar question just to answer that the solution was different in your particular case ..."* - ultimately its a *judgement call* with no easy rule. It depends "how similar" the questions are. Someday SO threads will get incorporated into a *network of relationships* structure, that can represent the subtleties of "how similar". Until then, we are stuck with arbitrating binary decisions about what belongs together.

Answer (score 3):

While other answers have a true angle at this situation, there's one that cruelly misses and that I find rather important. As commented by [charlietfl](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400688/answer-that-admits-its-answering-a-different-question-declined-for-naa-flag?cb=1#comment792207_400688):

> Curious why you would flag it at all if you aren't familiar with the subject?

In my opinion this a very, if not the most important aspect here because flags like these could have turned differently and removed valuable content.

The answer is completely relevant to the OP's problem and its many declinations. That the answerer is unaware of it is simply because of how far reaching autoloading problems are in PHP.

Please refrain from flagging content that you are not familiar with when it's about the correctness of said content or when you aren't 100% sure.

Comment: What about answers that are plainly NAA? I dont' need to be familiar with HTML to know that an answer that says "What have you tried?". If it takes you a long time to decide whether or not to flag an answer, then you probably shouldn't flag it. That is the rule of thumb I use.

Comment: You are right @10Rep, there is something about those cases, I might not have formulated it correctly but it's what I'm saying with "Please refrain from flagging [...] when it's about the correctness of said content!". Deciding that "what have you tried" is NAA is not about correctness.